# SQL to find min column and other columns associated when duplicate min columns exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, aggregation

Hi I am working on a specific case, where I need to find a min value and another column value of the same record when minimum values can be duplicate

```
Table A

  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
   1          10     07/21/2017
   1          9      07/22/2017
   1          9      07/23/2017
   2            20   07/23/2017
   2           20    07/24/2017
   3          15     07/21/2017
   3          15     07/21/2017

The output should be

ColumnD COlumnE  ColumnF
 1         9      07/23/2017
 2         20     07/24/2017
 3         15     07/21/2017
```

In a find the min value and associated latest date for it.

Answer (score 0):

You would do that with aggregation but with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by D order by B) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @TechJump . . . I cannot think of a reasonable way to use `avg()` to get the minimum value of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample result is the minimum of columnB and MAX of columnC, you can use the following SQL

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM (SELECT columnA,
               columnB,
               columnC,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnB, MAX(columnC) DESC) rmin
          FROM agg_dur
         GROUP BY columnA,
                  columnB,
                  columnC
        ) t
 WHERE t.rmin = 1
```

Result

```
columnA    columnB    columnC       rmin
1          9          2017-07-23    1
2          20         2017-07-24    1
3          15         2017-07-21    1
```